# How hard is it to find a job in the academia with a Muslim name in the UK?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom, stem

I found the following article on the Internet:

- [Candidates with Muslim-sounding names are three times more likely to be passed over for jobs](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/candidates-with-muslimsounding-names-three-times-more-likely-to-be-passed-over-for-jobs-a3459141.html)

What is the situation in the case of acadamia?

Comment: Go on over to your preferred university and look through a faculty list. Focus on STEM departments. See how many have non-English names (particularly the assistant professors). Come back with data.

Comment: I think this is probably impossible to answer with any reasonable evidence.  Anecdotally, my university (UK) has many academic and senior administrative staff with Muslim-sounding names including half (2/4) of our faculty Associate Deans and our University Pro-Vice-Chancellor for academic affairs.  There are certainly a range of biases that come into play in the hiring process, it's difficult to say if this is a significant one or not.

Comment: Could you be specific about the kind of job?  Most jobs are hard to get, but there's a big difference between computer science PhD student and humanities professor.  While discrimination is real, it does vary by discipline and the nature of the competition can be much more important than the discrimination.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, Chemical, and Computer Sc tenured faculty, and postdoc.

Comment: @JonCuster: I think that data would be of very limited assistance unless it were backed up with data on the names of applicants, and other details.  Knowing the number of Muslim names in the faculty doesn't even give you baseline proportions compared to applicants without the latter data.

Comment: @Ben - I agree that it is not data, but would quickly show if, in fact, there is a major problem. And, frankly, what is a "Muslim sounding" name in this day and age anyway?

Comment: @Ben Simply knowing the proportions do not show causal relation neither.

Comment: I would like to offer a (partial, biased) UK perspective that in general when study results are reported in the UK media one should be sceptical how many of the numbers and logical connectives have been understood by the journalist (or,sadly, those within UK universities writing the press releases). I also want to push back against the elision in the article that the OP links to between "Muslim-sounding names" and "Muslim names", given that no one thinks "G. Willow Wilson" is a "Muslim-sounding name"

Comment: @Greg: Sure, but it's a hell of a lot better than not knowing them.

Comment: @JonCuster "would quickly show if, in fact, there is a major problem" How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I estimate that not only it is not harmful on average to have a Muslim name in the UK academic job market (on average), but that it is a *clear advantage*.

"Diversity hires" are becoming more important to many departments, and regulatory requirements are put on faculties to adhere to these requirements. To my understanding, these regulatory requirements (at the university level or above) sometimes come with *diversity targets*, i.e., percentage of "diversity" candidates that are to be interviewed and possibly recruited (this is my understanding of the term "diversity *targets*"---i.e., that the target is a number. Some people in the comments claim there are no rigid numbers). Diversity candidates are clearly tagged in (some) recruitment cycles by different categories: BAME (black, Asian, Middle-Eastern), female, etc. Recruitment cycles are then *audited* for upholding diversity targets of this sort (again, it is my understanding that if a department does not uphold a certain minimal target (i.e., percentage. Just for example, only 5% are foreigners, or 5% are female) of "diversity" interviews, they will have to justify this in the audit and they may not be able to; therefore, departments are pressured in this way to fulfil a minimal number of "diversity interviews").

If you have a clearly "foreign name" (Middle Eastern) in the UK it thus definitely counts as a diversity-point in favour of your candidacy.
If you are also a **female Muslim**, my estimation is that you have a very good chance of being at least interviewed, assuming some minimal credential requirements are fulfilled.

*Important comment*: although diversity points can help in general, my estimation is that the major advantage a candidate has is not their ethnic/religious identity, but how well they are connected to people with influence *inside* the department, be it collaborator, colleague, or someone who comes from the same "clique" of colleagues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139416/discussion-on-answer-by-dilworth-how-hard-is-it-to-find-a-job-in-the-academia-wi). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230) before posting another comment.

Answer (score 16):

The way to obtain such numbers is by submitting application documents to job posting that are identical other than the name of the applicant. If the documents are sent to enough prospective employers and a statiscally significant difference is found, this can indeed be attributed to the name quite well.

This methodology does not work for faculty positions, as the nature of job applications is different. You can't just create a duplicate publication record of this kind. In many cases, successful applicants will be known to someone at the target university from conference talks, publications or collaborations.

One could compare numbers such as "fraction of students in discipline X with Muslim-sounding name" to "fraction of faculty in discipline X with Muslim-sounding name", but there are many differences between the makeup of the student population and faculty members, and firm conclusions will remain elusive that way.

So what can we say? There are plenty of academics in the UK with Muslim-sounding names, so such a name is not an unsurmountable disadvantage. Getting a job in academia is hard no matter what your name is. On the other hand, academia does not stand apart from the rest of society. It would be highly surprising if it is completely free from the anti-Muslim-sounding-name-bias found elsewhere.

Comment: "This methodology does not work for faculty positions" Pretty good studies have been done for gender discrimination in faculty hiring.  You just give your fake hiring committee consisting of faculty some CVs which are quite similar except for gender.  Then you find discrimination.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist That sounds like a lab experiment, not one in the wild. I definitely consider the results from this strong evidence for discrimination, but I'd hesitate to trust that specific numbers ("three times more likely") translate to real appointment procedures.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Unlike in industry, faculty hiring basically assumes that an applicant has a public track record in the form of publications, a website, speaking engagements, etc, all of which will be evaluated and checked (at least in some informal way) during hiring. Submitting a fake CV is not likely going to lead to any interviews at all, Muslim name or not.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth In theory, the way to deal with a 1% rate of applicants being invited for an interview is to submit a thousand fake CV with say 10% with Muslim sounding names.  This will fail for other reasons, like causing a failed search.  Hard to make this an ethical study.

Comment: @TerryLoring, that would require a lot of effort! :)

Comment: @paul garrett: The effort, and especially repeatability of the study, could be made much less by creating the appropriate analog of things like [snarXiv](http://davidsd.org/2010/03/the-snarxiv/) (snarXiv [paper generator](http://snarxiv.org/)) and [SCIgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCIgen) (SCIgen [paper generator](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/archive/scigen/#about)) and the [Postmodernism Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism_Generator) (PG [paper generator](https://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro ... true. And/but, then, as suggested by TerryLoring, generating this much extra work for hiring/postdoc committees at universities nation-wide in the U.S. could be viewed as reeeeeeally inappropriate.

Comment: @paul garrett: I have to admit I didn't think of this -- and thus we have an example for the phrase "unintended consequences" (or its stronger version, "collateral damage") -- but for what it's worth, if I had thought of it I still would have posted those links! (But probably with a nod towards the extra work of hiring committees having to look through all those documents, and yes, I'm thinking of [this current (U.S.) issue](https://www.reuters.com/world/us/pro-trump-activists-swamp-election-officials-with-sprawling-records-requests-2022-08-03/)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, it would actually be a "DoS" (=denial of service) attack on the hiring committees, the more I think of it! Adding 1,000 applications to my uni's math dept's faculty hiring would probably triple the total. Nationwide... yikes!?!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth "Submitting a fake CV is not likely going to lead to any interviews at all,"  I do not believe you would google all the hundreds of CVs before deciding who to phone interview.  Anyway, in a sensible study you just ask the participants:  Based on these CVs, who would you interview?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The vast majority of faculty have never had their own website.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: No, I don't need to google all hundreds of applicants. Search committees sort out those that don't rise to the top 20 or so right away. Once you're done to 20, you start to discuss the ones that are left, look at their publications in more detail, discuss them in committee. You will find fake profiles at this stage, and they get sorted out as well. As for websites: "The vast majority of faculty have never had their own website." I think you need to do an empirical study at a randomly selected department at an R1 university. You will find yourself wrong.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The vast majority of faculty do not work at R1s.  It would be reasonable to think it is a majority at R1s, at least in STEM.  "Search committees sort out those that don't rise to the top 20 or so right away."  Yes, and that's where the discrimination is likely to occur.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Right -- that's exactly where the discrimination will occur. I'm just saying that you won't be able to measure it because none of the other fake CVs with Christian/Western names will get a call-back either.

Comment: And I am saying it's easily measured in a controlled experiment; not in the wild.  Controlled experiments are the sensible way to do things.

Answer (score 5):

I'll make two observations about academia, though they aren't specific to UK.

First, as a group (and with exceptions), academics are generally less prejudiced than the overall population. My own view is that diversity is a strength and that if I want to learn something new, it is good to talk to people not just like myself.

Second, in a large university in a country with a diverse population, as I think is true of UK, there is value in having role models for students that they can directly relate to. This is, in a way, the flip side of the first observation. But it implies that a diverse faculty is helpful when it matches a diverse student body.

I conclude from the above that having a "foreign sounding" name, whether Muslim, or Nigerian, or Chinese is one of the lesser impediments to an academic career than having, say, a poor publication record or few people willing to recommend you highly. Yes, you will find discrimination, but I'd guess that it is more likely to be manifest outside the university than inside. We have a lot to learn, even in the twenty-first century.

I'll also note that it is good for "majority culture" students to see and learn from competent professionals from other cultures. That might even help us reach the twenty-second century.